# My answer in long division and synthetic division dont match

Tags: polynomials, soft-question, factoring

my problem was $2x^4 + x^3 -19x^2 + 18x + 5$ divided by $2x-5$

my answer in long division was : $x^3 + 3x^2 - 2x + 4$ and a remainder of $25$
my answer in synthetic division : $2x^3 + 11x^2 + 36x + 198$ and remainder of $995$

Comment: Why don't you just check which result (if any) is correct, by taking the quotient times $2x-5$ plus the remainder and expanding?

Comment: You can of course check your answers.  If you divide $f(x)$ by $g(x)$ this should give you a quotient $q(x)$ and a remainder $r(x)$.  That would mean that $f(x) = g(x)q(x)+r(x)$... so... try multiplying your answer by $2x-5$ and then add to the result your remainder.  It should be clear that $(2x^3+11x^2+\dots)\times (2x-5)$ will *not* have a leading term of $2x^4$ but will instead have a leading term of $4x^4$ and so must be wrong.

Comment: Shouldn’t $(2x^4…)\div (2x…)=x^3…$?

Comment: As for *why* your answer is wrong and what mistake you made... we have no way to comment on this since you have shown none of your work in how you got to those answers.

Comment: Doesn't the synthetic division shortcut allow you only to divide by polynomials $x-c$?  You would have to divide by $x-5/2$ and then adjust at the end.

Comment: @TedShifrin - That's my experience too.

Answer (score 1):

Your result from long division is correct. Indeed,
\begin{align*}
2x^4 + x^3 - 19x^2 + 18x + 5
& = 2x^4 - 5x^3 + 6x^3 - 15x^2 - 4x^2 + 10x + 8x - 20 + 25 \\
& = x^3(2x - 5) + 3x^2(2x - 5) - 2x(2x - 5) + 4(2x - 5) + 25 \\
& = (2x - 5)(x^3 + 3x^2 - 2x + 4) + 25,
\end{align*}
so
$$
\frac{2x^4 + x^3 - 19x^2 + 18x + 5}{2x - 5} = x^3 + 3x^2 - 2x + 4 + \frac{25}{2x - 5}.
$$